# how to fetch data from mysql as int instead of tuple in python

Tags: python, sql

this is my code:

```
x=va1.get()
y=va2.get()

conn=pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user="root",passwd="",db='billing')
q=conn.cursor()
q.execute(f"SELECT stock FROM items WHERE barcode = {x}")
rr=q.fetchone()
for i in rr:
         if y<=i[0]:
               messagebox.showinfo("Stock","You only have f{rr} to buy in f{x}")
         else:
               print("You have enough stock to buy this item")
```

va1 and va2 are variables from entries

this is my error:

if y<=i[0]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: "rr" is a tuple from which you take the only int item with "for i in rr". Therefore i is an int which doesn't allow "i[0]" subscription.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thanks for the answer but now I'm having a different error: tuple index out of range, I only have one data in tuple I think.

Comment: You're not accessing positions of a tuple anywhere, so what did you change?

Comment: @cricket_007 I used y<=rr[i][0] insterd of y<=i[0]:

Comment: Why do you need a loop at all? You're only selecting one column and at most one row

Comment: I strongly recommend learning some more Python and about programming in general. Do you understand the solution, what caused the issue?

Comment: Never use f-strings for SQL queries. It will allow SQL injection vulnerabilities. Give the arguments to execute as show in [the example from the docs](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only selecting one column, so you can do this, assuming that you always will get a database result

```
stock =q.fetchone()[0]
```

If you don't get any result, then you'll need to check for it and assign some default

```
rr =q.fetchone()
stock = -1 if rr is None else rr[0]
```

And you'd remove the for loop

Comment: In cases like this, I'm a fan of tuple unpacking rather than subscripting: `stock, = q.fetchone()` (which makes it clearer what the structure of the return value is)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like .fetchone() is only returning a single item.

Within that item, what you're iterating through look like they're ints. This means that i doesn't have an index.

Have you tried fetchall instead. (Or if it's a lot of data, fetchmany(n))?

Comment: There is one data in sql database for the sql function @Michael Streeing